# Wordpress upload folder

Tags: wordpress

i have a blog stored in Wordpress.com and I'm not very familiar with this yet. I really need to upload a folder from my computer (inside there is some html and js files) but the wordpress doesn't allow FTP access (I guess).
How can I solve this issue? Is it possible?
Maybe some administration plugin..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used FTP to upload files to wordpress in the past. Is it possible that your host is disabling you from doing so?

Comment: it is hosted in wordpress.com

Answer (score 2):

Word press does allow for FTP access I use microsoft web expressions 4 quite often.
Check out this site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_FileZilla or post your problem.
Thanks

Edit** missed your .com my mistake http://en.support.wordpress.com/ftp-access/ confirms your claim. HTML and JS are not allowed on wordpress.com a workaround may get you banned. Best to check with their support first.

Comment: What are the credentials to access the FTP ?

Comment: Sorry see edit, try using some of the good free hosters like 1and1 for your own wordpress host.

Answer (score 0):

You would need FTP access to your server that Wordpress is running on then you would need an FTP client like [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) to transfer the files